# Broken teffilin box

Tags: halacha, tefilin, genizah-storage, holy-objects, property

If a plastic teffilin case is broken by being chipped into different pieces, but the leather boxes as well as the leather straps are intact, do they need to put the whole teffilin in Geniza?

Or should they have the box fixed? Or should they put the box in a geniza and get a new box?

Sources would be appreciated

Comment: Do you mean the actual batim or the case? How are they broken?

Comment: As in leather or plastic?

Comment: In what way is it broken? The question is way too general

Comment: In addition to the previous comments: if you mean the batim, does that include the parchment (I.e. it's ripped) or just the leather box?

Comment: Why would a broken plastic case have anything to do with the straps? I'm worried there's something we're missing here

Comment: Just to clarify, there are three parts, the bayit (plur. batim) which is the square leather box enclosing the parchment, the retzuot which are the leather straps to wrap tefilin around the head/arm and the plastic cover for the batim which are cheap and easily replaceable items. You write the plastic case is broken, and you can just replace it then.

Comment: The plastic box covering the *batim* needs *geniza* because they are *tashmishei kedushah*. תשמישי מצווה - נזרקין, תשמישי קדושה - נגנזין. ואלו הן תשמישי מצווה: סוכה, לולב, שופר, ציצית. ואלו הן תשמישי קדושה: דלוסקמי ספרים, תפילין ומזוזות ותיק של ספר תורה ונרתיק של תפילין ורצועותיהן. https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%AA%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%A9_%D7%A7%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%94_%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%A9_%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%95%D7%94